# I have a Loan ID and and Address column. How do I find if there is more than one address linked to each loan?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find out which loans in my DB are secured by more than one property. For example, if there is a loan ID with two completely different addresses associated with it.

This is the code I've already tried.

```
Select * 
FROM [loan].[dim_property]
Where [account_id_bk] in (
              Select [account_id_bk]
              FROM [loan].[dim_property]
              Group by [account_id_bk]
               Having COUNT(distinct address1) > '1'                )
```

Not getting exactly what I want;.

Comment: Script seems ok. Can you please add some output data and data as you expected?

Comment: "`COUNT(distinct address1) > '1'`" -- in this context `1` is definitely a number not a string, so it shouldn't be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: "COUNT(distinct address1) > '1'"  not a issue @stickybit as SQL server auto covert this string to INT and provide expected result.

Comment: "Not getting exactly what I want" isn't a particularly meaningful problem description.  We don't know what you're getting or what you're expecting or what your inputs are.  When you attempt this query on a small controlled set of data, what is the result?  What was the expected result?  What was the sample data?

Comment: @mkRabbani: Maybe a misunderstanding... I didn't want to claim that it changes the result, it doesn't, because as you said there is an automatic conversion. But it is cleaner without the quotes and why forcing a conversion if you can give the right value from the start.

Comment: @stickybit you are correct.

Comment: My apologies. I'm trying to find all the loans in my DB that have more than one address secured against it. So if two separate addresses have the same Loan ID, I can see them in a group/together. My output at the moment is just a list of account ID's and Addresses in no particular order.

Comment: To get particular order, add ORDER BY clause at the end like - ORDER BY account_id_bk,address1

Comment: Thank you, if there is repeating addresses, what is the best way to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Learn to ask [smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Your reader has no knowledge of your schema. To write or correct queries against your schema one must know the DDL of the tables involved - most importantly the primary key, foreign key, and unique constraints. Your naming convention does not really help understanding of your query/schema either. **account_id_bk** - what does that mean?

There should

```
select prp.account_id_bk, count(*)
from loan.dim_property as prp 
group by prp.account_id_bk
having count(*) > 1
order by prp.account_id_bk;
```

That answers your question (if I guessed correctly). I assumed that account_id_bk identifies a "loan" so any property that has the same account is security for that loan. But the query you posted suggests that you have a different actual goal from the question you asked - your title suggests the same thing.

If needed, you can then stuff that query into a cte and join it to dim_property to retrieve the property rows for this set of loans. That would be a good leaning exercise for you.